# Deleting rows in a second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if someone could help me
I have two tables 1) profile  2) mailbox_conversation
Each table has a common column called profile_id

I would like to find all the members in the profile table who have a membership_id = 107 (i.e. get a subset of members who have membership type 107 and they will be listed in an array by profile_id)
Then using that subset of members, find all the conversations in the table mailbox_conversation that have a profile_id in the subset - thus many emails may have the same profile_id and I would like them all deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find emails which correspond to profiles with membership_id = 107

```
select m.id
from mailbox_conversation m
join profile p on p.profile_id = m.profile_id
                  and p.membership_id = 107
```

Delete those records

```
delete from mailbox_conversation
using mailbox_conversation, profile
where profile.profile_id = mailbox_conversation.profile_id
      and profile.membership_id = 107;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82a55/1/0) for playing around.

Comment: @vels4j Thanks. Result is the same either way. See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9be16/3/0).

Comment: For the benefit of those who arrive from a search, not all other RDBMS allow `delete ... using` (pity, that). You can rewrite the query with a full `SELECT` query as the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t1.profile_id from mailbox_conversation t1 where t1.profile_id in 
(select t2.profile_id from profile t2 where t2.membership_id = 107 )
```